# How to get the content inside div class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a python script to extract the details from a website. My code is below.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'my_company_website'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"navigator-content"})

print (containers)
```

I'm getting the output like this

```
<div 
class="navigator-content" data-issue-table-model-state="" data-selected-issue="" data-session-search-state="">
</div>
```

I want the contents inside this as output. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
inside = re.split(r'>*</*div', containers)[1].split()
```

`inside` is this list:

```
['class="navigator-content"',
 'data-issue-table-model-state=""',
 'data-selected-issue=""',
 'data-session-search-state=""']
```